# Ran out of "Datastore Small Operations" quota unexpectedly

Tags: python, google-app-engine

So this code:

```
all_nodes = Nodes.query()
country_nodes = []
for n in all_nodes:
    country_nodes.append([n.country, all_nodes.filter(Nodes.country == n.country).count()])
```

Just nuked my `Datastore Small Operations` quota without even finishing the operation?

Whats the right way to get the above list?

Comment: Got it. The problem was the countries are not unique. Some have 1000 entries, so there was like a million ops instead of 2 or three thousand. Getting the countries first then putting them in a set `countries = set([i.country for i in all_nodes])` then filtering with that has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GAE, it may be better to keep track of the totals for each country when you write a new record. Then you can have a single read to find out a country total. For example, you could add a new model type:

```
class Country(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Then, when you add a new node, you can get the corresponding `Country` record and increment its `count` property.

In your example, when you do `all_nodes.filter(...)`, you're running a new query for each `n` in `all_nodes`. The following, should be a cheaper method of calculating totals. But it is probably more expensive than tracking country totals when you write new records.

```
from collections import defaultdict

country_nodes = defaultdict(int)
for n in Nodes.query():
    country_nodes[n.country] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `limit=n` (`n`=the minimal You can afford) in `count()` or `fetch()`
For, example, to look if there exist any record use `count(limit=1)`
Also `filter()` on index does `count()` minimal.
It is very easy to get "Datastore Small Operations quota exceeded" in a large database of records. Always think on how many records there could be in result, or will be processed nonindexed inside :)